# Cannot run official react-native-mapbox-gl sample project?

Tags: android, react-native, npm, mapbox

I downloaded the sample project it has an unusual react-native project structure.

When open it drops down like this(screenshot given below).

[image]

And then we open the example(screenshot given below)

[image]

Usually the structure exists as in the second screenshot.

And when i open the android part inside the android-studio the gradle doesn't get build.

Because `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` this doesn't get applied.

When i try to download node_modules from inside the example project it fails.

But from outside from parent folder it gets successful.

If anybody has successfully ran this project,please help me.And if your are kind enough to try u can downloaded it in the below link.

https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl